# How can I get my text to update when I press my button? Can someone confirm this is written correctly?

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground

This is what I currently have:

```
enter code here

import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct FirstApp: View {
@State var a = 0
var body: some View {
    Button("test") {
        increment()
        print(a)
        }
    // this is the text i would want to increment on my UI as i press the       button 
    Text(String(a))
}
// function to increment 
func increment() {
    a += 1
}
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(FirstApp())
```

It seems that the text keeps displaying 0 on the preview however the console does increment my variable a. Thank you in advance and I apologize for such a noob question.

Comment: It may be a bug of the playground. Try it on the simulator or a real device, it works fine

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thank you very much for clarifying and saying it works fine.  You are right.  It is a bug with the playground.  I discovered that disabling the console and “show results” fixed my preview.  As a note: I am using Swift Playgrounds 3.4.1.  Thank you for responding to my question!